# Rails 4: image_tag not working for images in emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Here is the code I have:

`<p><%= image_tag "/assets/logos/#{@company_name.downcase}_logo.jpg" %></p>`

When the email is sent, and I view the email in my email client, the image is not showing up. It appears like a broken image

Anyone else run into this issue?

Here is my `development.rb`

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_controller.asset_host = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
end
```

Working code:

`<p><%= image_tag("logos/#{@company_name.downcase}_logo.jpg") %></p>`

Comment: did you check whether image is there in assets/images folder only and not in sub folders. Also check whether it is .jpg or .JPG ..because even that matters when loading image

Comment: Yeah, they're where they're supposed to be. If I visit `http://localhost:3000/assets/logos/logo.jpg` in my browser, then the image shows up

Comment: "image_tag" takes you to "assets/images" folder directly. So try pasting your image into mentioned folder and try using <p><%= image_tag "#{@company_name.downcase}_logo.jpg" %></p>... and see if it works.

Comment: This is what shows up in my email client (Gmail): `https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/PnNleEdztcmZ97Y2pmx8mwGjwF2hMIx9009CdiWdTaQy4n_1LunBEB86hfudoeFGYYzGDog0NQr6skhrftog=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost:3000/logos/elan_logo.jpg` and the image shows up as broken

Comment: can you tell your exact path of your image ..from root of rails folder

Comment: `root/app/assets/images/logos/logo_name_logo.jpg`

Comment: try this <p><%= image_tag "/logos/#{@company_name.downcase}_logo.jpg" %></p>

Comment: @RahulSambari tried that too... no luck :(

Comment: one doubt..when your image is logo_name.jpg, why are you trying with _logo.jpg in your cocde? ..should it be "logo_#{@company_name.downcase}.jpg"

Comment: @RahulSambari sorry, the image is `logo_name_logo.jpg`

Comment: did you check that your #{@company_name.downcase} does not give any extra space ? did you check the length of it ? like it matches with the original picture name?

Comment: Yeah, I checked all of that... no dice... if I go to `http://localhost:3000/assets/logos/logo_name_logo.jpg` directly, the logo shows up

Comment: I got it working! code updated above

Comment: Can you tell me the exact reason for the issue as I am using paperclip and facing the same exact problem. 
`http://localhost:3001/system/courses/29/assets/objs/216/original/Administrator.jpg?1406013237`
This url works just fine in browser but in mail I get some `googleusercontent` url already appended to my url... :(
cant get it to work

Comment: @adil - how are you calling `image_tag` in your view?

Comment: `<%= imaage_tag "asset.avatar.url" %>` this way...
I think it might be the case that gmail is not able to show it while I am running it on a local server perhaps?

Comment: Try this: `<img src="<%= image_url('/assets/logos/#{@company_name.downcase}_logo.jpg') %>">`

Comment: @dennismonsewicz - are you saying you resolved this? If so, would you consider posting your own answer and marking it as accepted? This question is showing up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `http‌​://localhost:3000/lo‌​gos/elan_logo.jpg`. Google will load image from this url to their cache. And `https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/PnNleEdztcmZ97Y2pmx8‌​mwGjwF2hMIx9009CdiWd‌​TaQy4n_1LunBEB86hfud‌​oeFGYYzGDog0NQr6skhr‌​ftog=s0-d-e1-ft#http‌​://localhost:3000/lo‌​gos/elan_logo.jpg` will display image correctly.

But Google can't access to localhost.

You should change `config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://your_active_domain.com'`

Comment: Indeed, update your `asset_host` and make sure to include the full path including `http://` or `https://` in the URL

Answer (score 0):

In contact mailer add image as an atachement

```
def sendCode(message,email)
 @message = "message: #{message} "
 attachments.inline['img1.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("public/emails", "img1.png"))
 attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join("public/emails", "logo.png"))
 mail(to: email, subject: 'Sample Email')
end
```

And in your html.erb file you can call the attachement image like that

```
<%= image_tag attachments['logo.png'].url, alt: 'image', class: 'photo' -%>
```

it will work with you